# create gRPC on C++

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-web

Suppose I have a service on a microservice architecture in python and fastApi that communicates via gRPC, for example, an online bookstore. There is also logic written in C++, from which I want to create a new microservice

From this question: how do they make a microservice with gRPC in c++? Maybe it's easier to wrap the service in fastApi and call the compiled dll file?

Answer (score 0):

gRPC has [a whole tutorial on their website](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/). [Here's](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) a rundown of the basics.

The examples use [proto](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/cpp-generated/) to define the messages and services.

You have `grpc::ServerBuilder` used to make your server instance.

You make your service implementations that extend the generated service classes. Each procedure gets a `grpc::ServerContext*` as well as the appropriate request, response, reader and writer.